# use device uuid in controller using onsen-ui

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

i'm building a app using angularjs and onsen-ui in the Monaca cloud based development tool. this works great, but i can not figure out how to get device params like UUID into a controller.

I initialize onsen using :

```
var module = ons.bootstrap('my-app', ['onsen']);
```

then for example i have a main controller like this:

```
module.controller('MainController', function($scope) {

    $scope.deviceid = device.model;

});
```

in this example device.uuid is ofcourse not working.
does anybody know how to access these device params?

i included the cordova device plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the device proprieties, like the UUID, in this way:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="my-app">
      <head>
        <title>Device Properties Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        
        var module = ons.bootstrap('my-app', ['onsen']);
          
        module.controller('MainController', function($scope) {

          // Wait for device API libraries to load
          //
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

          // device APIs are available
          //
          function onDeviceReady() {
            var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
            element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' +
                                'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
                                'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                                'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                                'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
                                'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
          }

        });
          
        

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
      </body>
    </html>
```